# What am I and my weird family?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My father was given my grandfather's name.
>   Like all the other names were gone?
>   Even though, their last names are not the same.
>   Because my grandfather doesn't even have one!
>
> When I was born, I didn't want to be called the same,
>   I wanted my name to be cool instead!
>   Even so, they still gave me the same name...
>   But gave me a cute last name as I pled.

What am I?
And who are my relatives?

Hint 1

> Removing one space from the last line would give you a major hint :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you, your father and grandfather are

> C# , C++ , C programming languages

My father was given my grandfather's name. Like all the other names were gone?

> Father C++ and grandfather C have same given name - and possibly other names D, E, F, G were already [programming lanuages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)

Even though, their last names are not the same. Because my grandfather doesn't even have one!

> The grandfather C language has no suffix

When I was born, I didn't want to be called the same, I wanted my name to be cool instead!

> A proposed named for C# was COOL standing for C-like Object Oriented Language  [C sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))

Even so, they still gave me the same name...But gave me a cute last name as I pled.

> Named after C but - from the hint missing a space in the last line is *acute* - and sharp is acute

Comment: That's right, good job! :)

Comment: @GintasK could you please explain how would taking off the space in the last line act as a hint?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal , if we remove the space from "a cute" we get "acute" which is a synonym for sharp :)

Comment: Thoughtful. The hint is a recursive puzzle in itself :)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you could be talking about

> Apple's iPad and its successors

My father was given my grandfather's name.
Like all the other names were gone?
Even though, their last names are not the same.
Because my grandfather doesn't even have one!

> The original iPad was called just that. The next model (which was smaller) was christened iPad Mini.

When I was born, I didn't want to be called the same,
I wanted my name to be cool instead!
Even so, they still gave me the same name...
But gave me a cute last name as I pled.

> The smallest of the iPad series was called iPad Pro. Also, the use of '**I**' four times could be a pointer to an Apple product. *This answer doesn't quite fit well with Pro being cute or wanting a different name, but I thought I'd put this out there.*

Comment: Good try, but not the answer I'm looking for :) It should fit every clue in the riddle, and there are more clues there :)

Comment: I also thougth about smartphones/devices but is too broad to be the answer